# Unable to trace ASP form processor script

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp-classic, webforms

I am pretty new to ASP. Can anyone suggest how to edit an ASP form script to send proper authenticated mails. I am unable t find the proper script where it is edited.

It is not being sent at present!

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking Classic ASP or ASP.net? Your tags make this ambiguous, and the answer will be very different depending on which

Here's a Classic ASP example - the connection timeout line is optional, and you should leave out the ssl line if you aren't using ssl - obviously.

smtpserverport will usually be 25 or 587

```
<%
Dim objMail, iConfg, Flds
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConfg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConfg.Fields
With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "your.smtpserver.address"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "yourmailboxname@yourdomain.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "yourpassword"
        .Update
End With
.Configuration = iConfg

objMail.Subject = Request("subject")
objMail.From = Request("senderemail")
objMail.To = "yourmailboxname@yourdomain.com"
objMail.TextBody= Request("message")
objMail.Send

set objMail = nothing

response.write "Thank you for emailing us, we will be in touch shortly"
%>
```

If the script above was in a file called sendcdo.asp, then your form would be something  like this

```
<form method="post" action="sendcdo.asp"> 
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
  Your email:<input type="text" name="senderemail" /><br />
  Your message<textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

Comment: Thanks for the help John... but can you specify where do I add this. I am unable to find any processing script.

Comment: It would go on the page which is the target (the "action" attribute) of your form.  If your form contained a text field called "subject" and a textarea called "message" then you could use objMail.Subject = Request("subject") and objMail.TextBody = Request("message) in your cdo message object

Comment: Thanks for the clear briefing John, but that seems to be issue! I cannot find the form action script in the hosting panel... Where can I find it to edit?

Comment: A lot of Linux Apache hosting packages come with a formmail CGI script, but on IIS you usually have to write your own.  Copy the above, enter your own server settings where appropriate, save and upload to your server, and that's your script

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention John but it uses <form method="post" action="%RunAtServer%"> ... so do I change that or make edits somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, change the action attribute to the name of the asp script you create, as per my answer.  I've never seen action="%RunAtServer%" before.  Maybe it's something specific to your server setup and you need to ask your tech support.  Aslo, getting back to my original point, Are you looking for a Classic ASP or an ASP.net solution.  Classic ASP is "turned off" by default in current versions of IIS, so you need to be sure it's been enabled before you try any of the above.